# Emulator, Device, Android Studio Layout Differences in Notification

Tags: android, android-layout, emulation, device

I'm trying to layout a fragment for a notification... the emulator and layout in the Android Studio designer are fine.

(Emulator Example)

[image: layout on emulator]

(Designer Example)
[image: layout in android studio]

But when the app is run on the target device the layout is not aligned properly.

(Layout on Device)
[image: Layout on device]

The device is an s7 edge with resolution 1440*2560, screen size 5.5 inch, and 360dp smallest width.

I created an emulator based on these specs and am running the app on it.

The layout is in res folder layout-sw360dp-xxxhdpi

There are other layout folders:

layout-sw320dp-hdpi

layout-sw360dp-xhdpi

layout-sw360dp-xxhdpi

layout-sw411dp-xxxhdpi

I have tried scaling imageviews, fitxy, fitstart, etc...

I have carefully checked the density pixel sizes for each imageview, layout, and background.

Layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/media_notification_large_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:padding="0dp">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_far_left"
android:layout_width="6.5dp"
android:layout_height="112dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:src="@mipmap/note_far_left" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_picture_top"
android:layout_width="133.5dp"
android:layout_height="13.5dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_far_left"
android:src="@mipmap/note_picture_top" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_picture"
android:layout_width="85dp"
android:layout_height="85dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_picture_top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_far_left"
android:background="@drawable/silver_note"
android:src="@drawable/silver_note" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_picture_bottom"
android:layout_width="85dp"
android:layout_height="13.5dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_picture"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_far_left"
android:src="@mipmap/note_picture_bottom" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_title_text_top"
android:layout_width="172.75dp"
android:layout_height="6.5dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_picture_top"
android:src="@mipmap/note_title_text_top" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_picture_right_top"
android:layout_width="48.5dp"
android:layout_height="32.25dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_picture_top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_picture"
android:src="@mipmap/note_picture_right_top" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_picture_right_bottom"
android:layout_width="14.25dp"
android:layout_height="66.25dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_picture_right_top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_picture"
android:src="@mipmap/note_picture_right_bottom" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_title_text_bottom"
android:layout_width="172.75dp"
android:layout_height="13.5dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/note_title"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_picture_right_top"
android:src="@mipmap/note_title_text_bottom" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/note_shb1"
android:layout_width="68.5dp"
android:layout_height="13.25dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_title_text_bottom"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_picture_right_bottom"
android:background="@mipmap/note_shb1"
android:fontFamily="@font/digital_7_mono"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Shuffle"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textSize="9.25sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/note_shb2"
android:layout_width="68.5dp"
android:layout_height="13.25dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_title_text_bottom"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_shb1"
android:background="@mipmap/note_shb2"
android:fontFamily="@font/digital_7_mono"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Hands Free"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textSize="9.25sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/note_shb3"
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="13.25dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_title_text_bottom"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_shb2"
android:background="@mipmap/note_shb3"
android:fontFamily="@font/digital_7_mono"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Bluetooth"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textSize="9.25sp" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_button_top"
android:layout_width="207dp"
android:layout_height="18dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_shb1"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_picture_right_bottom"
android:clickable="true"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:src="@mipmap/note_button_top" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_shuffle"
android:layout_width="34.25dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_button_top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_picture_right_bottom"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/note_shuffle_selector" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_back"
android:layout_width="34.25dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_button_top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_shuffle"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/note_back_selector" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_stop"
android:layout_width="34.25dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_button_top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_back"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/note_stop_selector" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_play"
android:layout_width="34.25dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_button_top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_stop"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/note_play_selector" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_next"
android:layout_width="34.25dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_button_top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_play"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/note_next_selector" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_hands"
android:layout_width="35.75dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_button_top"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_next"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/note_hands_selector" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/note_title"
android:layout_width="137dp"
android:layout_height="25.75dp"
android:layout_below="@id/note_title_text_top"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_picture_right_top"
android:background="@mipmap/note_title_text"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:fontFamily="@font/digital_7_mono"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingStart="1dp"
android:paddingEnd="1dp"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="@string/emergency_broadcast"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textSize="16sp" />

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/note_power"
android:layout_width="35.75dp"
android:layout_height="25.75dp"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/note_title"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/note_title"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@drawable/note_power_selector" />
```

(edit: added code for notification builder)
code to build notification:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
    }else{
        builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle());
    }

            builder
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
            .setSubText(metadataCompat.getText(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DISPLAY_SUBTITLE))
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setContentIntent(pContentIntent);



    return builder;
```

I'm out of ideas, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that width of the @id/note_title_text_bottom equals to the sum of note_title and note_power in all your layout files (for all the screen sizes). Otherwise, something is not right with the @mipmap/note_title_text_bottom" for one of the densities. 
Anyway, it's better to use relative sizes and scale you drawables instead of using multiple layouts with absolute values, which is really hard to maintain and scale.

Comment: Thanks...  I'll check it

Comment: No worries. It's also worth setting scale:fitXY for id/note_title_text_bottom in all your layouts (if the sum of the image views, I've posted above is correct for all the layouts).

Comment: @me_ have you tried to add android:scaleType="fitXY" to note_title_text_bottom in all your layout files?

Comment: It turned out to be a minute rounding error combined with the phone reporting its resolution incorrectly...  i set all imageviews to fitxy and fudged the image sizes the tiny bit needed to make all layouts "exact"

Answer (score 1):

ensure that you have placed the slices image in the same dpi.

1- its better to achieve this using the xml drawable background of parent layout and add left rectangle top left.

2- using android:scaleType="FIT_XY" to achieve this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and I will keep that in mind for future projects...  however, what's wrong with this one?

Comment: I thought about this for a bit, and I agree that in some instances this can make things easier.  However, it doesn't account for selectors very well.   When you are dealing with buttons that have selectors as src/backgrounds this approach means making "full-sized" backgrounds for each button and selector state...  doable and relatively easily, but it jacks up the size of the apk/app bundle considerably (most likely) to achieve the same effect.  Thank you for the thought, I will keep it in mind and look for places where its implementation makes sense.